# Is there a way to access files off a locked phone with a black screen?

Tags: lock-screens, data-recovery, motorola-droid

So my Droid 2 died on me and went grey screen with lines. I can't see anything and I can't access my files.

Is there any way to maybe project the screen or access it so I can unlock the phone?

Comment: Did you happen to have developer options enabled with USB debugging turned on?

Comment: Yes, that is normally one of the first things I turn on.

Comment: I updated my answer below to point to a different ADB-based solution (Droid@Screen) that works better than the one I originally linked to (androidscreencast).  Please check out the new link and see if it helps you.  I'll delete this comment after a while, but I wanted to make sure that you didn't miss the subtle change to my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have adb debugging turned on, you should be able to use [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/) from your PC to control your device over adb. There's nothing to install on your device, as long as the adb daemon is running.

Once you have that going, you can use the device from the PC as you would if the screen was working.

Also, if you know what files you're looking to pull off the device and how to navigate the Linux filesystem, you can grab them with 'adb pull ' from your PC. Again, this depends on USB debugging having already been turned on and previously used with the PC in question.

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile screen is not working properly then use your mobile model PC suite to access files.Some Android devices require USB debugging option to work PC Suite.First only check your phone without debugging if it is not working then turn on USB debugging option and reconnect USB again to your PC.

Comment: Good accept how does one enable debug i the screen does not work.

Comment: Sorry my mistake Frank but as you have mentioned in above comment that you have turned on debug before crash so you did not need to do it again so find a PC suite and try.

Answer (score 0):

You can mirror thought mobile screen to your PC via certain apps.
Check them out [here](http://www.prophethacker.com/2015/07/how-to-mirror-android-mobile-screen-to-window-pc.html#sthash.msTHhHHp.dpbs).
Try downloading **Motorola PC Suite**, it might help you.

Comment: Not sure this will work if I have to install an application to the phone first.

Answer (score -1):

Did you apply Hard reset(Recovery mode) to get access to your phone.You will lost all of your data but your mobile will start.This is best way to make your phone as when you started it first time.

Comment: Broken screen only purpose right now is to access data.

Comment: Have you tried yet to make a USB connection with computer?